# Efficient way to write this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to order the records by 3 columns and then select a particular ID and the record before that plus the row after that. Here is my query:

```
;With Cte As
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By Book, PageINT, [IDAuto]) as RowNum,  [IdAuto]

      FROM CCWiseInstr2
)
Select * From Cte
    Where RowNum = (Select RowNum From Cte
    Where IdAuto = 211079)
        UNION
Select * From Cte
    Where RowNum = (Select RowNum - 1 From Cte
    Where IdAuto = 211079)
    UNION
Select * From Cte
    Where RowNum = (Select RowNum + 1 From Cte
    Where IdAuto = 211079)
```

What could the other efficient way to write this query. At the moment the query takes about `336 ms` after creating all indexes which looks like a bit higher to me.

Here is the plan for the query:

http://gyazo.com/9a7f1c37d4433665d0949acf03c4561c

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Do you have an index on IDAuto?

Comment: Sql server 2012 as tagged in  the question. Yes IDAuto is clustered index.

Comment: And I have non-clustered index on (Book, PageINT, IDAuto) as 1 index. I have around 0.4 million rows in the table.

Comment: For starters, try a composite nonclustered index on IdAuto , Book, PageINT, IDAuto and move the WHERE clause to the CTE expression.  I would expect that will result in a single index seek instead of scanning the index multiple times.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP: That will the change query itself because when RowNum for that ID would become 1 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this query:

```
;With Cte As
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By Book, PageINT, [IDAuto]) as RowNum,  [IdAuto]       
        FROM CCWiseInstr2
)
Select RowNum, IDAuto From Cte
    Where RowNum IN ( 
        Select RowNumber  From 
            (
                Select  RowNum - 1 as RowNumPrev, 
                        RowNum as RowNum, 
                        RowNum + 1 as RowNumNext 
                        From Cte
                            Where IdAuto = 211079 
            ) vw unpivot ( 
                            RowNumber For 
                                    IdAuto IN (RowNumPrev, RowNum, RowNumNext ) 
                         ) unpw )
```

Instead of `UNION` just use `UNPIVOT` which will convert your columns into rows which you could then use in `IN`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Excellent. This only took **146 ms**. A considerable improvement!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LEAD and LAG functions with SQL Server.  Here's a great article on Simple Talk covering all of the options.  (Code below is untested)

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-2012-window-function-basics/

```
SELECT
  [IdAuto],
  LAG([IDAuto], 1) OVER(Order By Book, PageINT, [IDAuto]) AS PreviousSale,
  LEAD([IDAuto], 1) OVER(Order By Book, PageINT, [IDAuto]) AS NextSale
FROM
  CCWiseInstr2
WHERE [IdAuto] = 211079;
```

Comment: I had to change your query to `Select * From
(
 SELECT
   [IdAuto],
   LAG([IDAuto], 1) OVER(Order By Book, PageINT, [IDAuto]) AS PreviousSale,
   LEAD([IDAuto], 1) OVER(Order By Book, PageINT, [IDAuto]) AS NextSale
 FROM
   CCWiseInstr2
) vw Where vw.IdAuto = 211079` otherwise I would get NULL as previousSale and NextSale and if I change it to that this is much slower takes about 1.2 seconds. That's 3.5 times slower than my original version.

Comment: I have no indication of the column sizes, cardinality of the data or volume of rows, so your row_number over the table might perform reasonably well but LEAD and LAG are the functions implemented to do exactly what you are trying to do.  That said, I did not test the code before I wrote it, but instead tried to illustrate how you might use it.